# Android- start activity from service by sending already running process to background

Tags: android, android-service, android-activity

I have a background service `BGService` , it displays an Activity `BGServActivity` when certain event occurs. I have override onBackPressed to finish the displayed Activity `BGServActivity`.

Suppose, UI of Application `App_XYZ` is currently displaying. And my service `BGService` is triggered by the event and `BGServActivity` is displayed. And When i press back it closes the current Activity `BGServActivity` and displays the  previous UI from Application `App_XYZ` .

But i want the UI from `App_XYZ` to be sent to background when i start `BGServActivity` from my `BGService`.

**My question is**

Is there any special flag or something that i can do to send the previously displaying UI from another activity to sent to background before starting My `BGServActivity`  from My service `BGService`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If App_XYZ is "sent to background" then what should the user see when they press back from BGServActivity?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sending to background'? When BGServActivity starts, App_XYZ's UI must be going into the background automatically.. isn't it so? Sorrey, but I am not quite getting your problem

Comment: @dev_android, App_XYZ's UI  doesnot go to background on launching Activity : BGServActivity from service :  BGService

Comment: @goto10 i don't know the name for that but i am referring to the ##main screen## UI that is shown when our phone starts up - like desktop in PC. User should see the ##main screen## when they press back from BGServActivity

Comment: does BGServActivity activity present in App_XYZ? If yes then you can do something using application class. Or do you have control over App_XYZ if BGServActivity is part of App_XYZ if you have control over App_XYZ you can sent intent to close App_XYZ.

Comment: @HellBoy no App_XYZ can be any application.

Comment: @all - thanks for your help, i found the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871949/android-start-activity-from-service-by-sending-already-running-process-to-backg/7872293#7872293

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to force the user to go to the Home screen when your Activity closes, you can do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

I advise against this though. The standard behavior when closing an activity should be to return to the previously viewed activity.

Comment: thanks, i picked your idea and mixed with mine to achieve the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got solution.

First show the HOME Screen as [goto10's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871949/android-start-activity-from-service-by-sending-already-running-process-to-backg/7872142#7872142)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then-after open my Activity `BGServActivity`

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(getBaseContext(), BGServActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putBoolean("IS_FROM_SERVICE", true);
        //add extras
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);
```

And its working... :D